# Calling php script from JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have spent all morning trying to figure out how I can call a PHP script from my JavaScript function and then return a value to output. I am not sure whether I can do this with just JavaScript or whether I have to include some Ajax aswell?

Here is the main page

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function (){       
        $("select").change(function(){
            var currentValue = parseInt($(this).find("option:selected").val());
            //Call Script script.php here
            $("#output").html(result);
        })
    }); 
</script>   
</head>
<body>
    <select name="select">
        <option value='1' >1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
    </select>
    <div id="output"><!---OUTPUT HERE----></div>
```

And here is the script I want to call (I have simplified it all down to make it easier to understand)

```
<?php
    $result = $currentValue + 1;
?>
```

Basically I want it to read in the `currentValue` variable and output the result variable back to the webpage, to be outputted again.

Comment: Have a look at [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: What's the use of increasing a value like that? You need to store the value using for example like MySQL!

Comment: What do you mean by increasing it like that, the php script i have written is very long, too long to post here that involves mysql and all that, i just made it simple to show the fact, that i need to get the currentValue into the php script and get the result value out and back to the main page

Comment: look at this example I wrote .. you can download the files http://devpazzi.com/how-to-get-data-from-php-script-with-ajax-jquery/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Javascript:
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "example.com/script.php?currentValue="+currentValue ,
            dataType: "json",
            statusCode: {
                200: function (result)
                {
                    $("#output").html(result.value);
                }
            }
        });


// PHP 
<?php 
$result = $_GET["currentValue"] + 1;
echo json_encode(array("value" => $result));

 ?>
```

Comment: Hi, i am trying your code now, but i get an error on the last line `echo json_encode(array("value" => $result);`

Comment: ok, i just tried it, but whenever i select another option from the dropdown, nothing appears? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Do you replaced "//Call Script script.php here" with the $.ajax ?

Comment: yes i replaced it exactly like that, but still it doesnt display anything

Comment: Edited my answer, updated line $("#output").html(result.value)

Comment: ok brilliant, that works perfectly, i have small question though, it works when i select another option from the dropdown, but as soon as i open the webpage it displays nothing, in other words if i refresh the webpage it displays nothing for the default option 1, it only starts displaying when i select a new option, any ideas on how i can fix this?

Comment: You can manually trigger the "change" event with: $('select').trigger('change');

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('<url>', {currentValue : currentValue}, function(){}, 'json');
```

**< url>** example ajax/phpScript

Here **ajax** is controller and **phpScript** is the method in that controller

```
public function phpScript()
{
 $phpScript = $_POST['phpScript'];

//add your code 

}
```